# addHours method for java Time program

Tags: java, time

How do i create an addHours(int h) method which changes the time to h hours later while "wrapping around" 24. If 4 is added to 23, the number of hours would be 3

where im at:

```
public static void addHours(int hrs) {
    int newHours = hours + hrs;
    if newHours>24 then newHours = newHours%2+hrs;
    return newHours;
}
```

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Comment: Could you update this post with the code you have tried?

Comment: @laylarenee is that helpful?

Comment: Please tell me the pseudo code is intended on being as such and isn't real code.

Comment: @hannahm it's not very clear when you mishmash code with pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question did not compile, so I assume that was just psuedo-code. It sounds like you want to create a function to return int, instead of a void, which doesn't return a value.

```
    public static int addHours(int hours, int hrs)
    {
        int newHours = hours + hrs;
        if (newHours > 24)
        {
            return newHours % 24;
        }
        else
        {
            return newHours;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For brevity I would just use the ternary operator: 
`return (newHours > 24) ? newHours % 24 : newHours;`. However, shouldn't 24 return 0? In which case just use `return newHours % 24;`

Answer (score 0):

First your code wouldn't compile as written. Second your method signature was incorrect to be able to return a value. However, this should work for you.

```
public static int addHours(int hrs) {
    int newHours = hours + hrs;
    return newHours % 24 ? newHours - 24 : newHours;
}
```

Comment: This will not work as desired if greater than 24 hours is added.